Hit by Lightning
I have been searching for this film for about a decade. I think I saw it on PBS from 2000 to 2003. I recall two things:

I remember that there were to feral children (or something like that) and one of them freaks out and runs outside (maybe they were in a cave) and s/he gets hit by lightning.
The other scene I remember is this very old guy with a big white beard walking through an alley (maybe like a castle alley, so I'm guessing it would have been set in middle ages?) and I think he gets killed there (and maybe a lot of people do? I don't remember)

I have watched thousands of films in search for this one. If anyone has any idea about it let me know. Also my memory may be incorrect and these might be two distinct movies, the memories might have merged.

You might be talking about the TV adaptation of Gormenghast from 2000. It aired on PBS, takes place in a castle in an ancient, gothic city and features a couple of characters with big white beards (and many scenes that take place in alleyways). But more to the point, from the PBS recap:

He sees a girl who jumps from branch to branch. She is the Wild Thing, the girl who has grown up a feral child in the woods, following the death of her mother, Keda... The Wild Thing runs from the cave and is struck by lightning.

The series is available on Youtube in 24 parts; here's the first one.
